# Where can I find deals to buy photo editing softwares?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Here is the deal (pun intended). I created this question because there are numerous deals going on right now (November 2010) for Adobe softwares, [including 30% off Lightroom 3](http://www.1001noisycameras.com/2010/11/adobe-deals-lightroom-3-full-for-200-elements-9-for-50ar.html) ($200 instead of $300) and Photoshop CS5. Both Aperture and Lightroom are really useful applications for photographers and the source of many questions here. Switching from PS to LR was one of the best decision I made last year.

Now the issue is, how can we (or should we) share that info on photo.se? Deals are limited to a certain period of time, which makes any official "answer" irrelevant pretty fast. Can that question be a community Wiki instead, where we list deals chronologically?

In any case, feel free to mod down / flag / nuke this question if this is outside photo.se policy.

Answer (score 3):

Shopping recommendations, buying alerts, good deals, or anything like that are not appropriate for this (or any other Stack Exchange) site. As a matter of fact, this is being codified in many of the Stack Exchange FAQs as [official policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: First, as I pointed out, I think it's worth discussing anything that is beneficial to the photo community. Lightroom or Aperture are hard to avoid once you get serious about photo, and with the rampant piracy going on, I think it was not a bad idea to point out a way to buy Lightroom for cheap.

Comment: Second, I do have a problem with the link you are pointing out, because the example they give is rather silly. I quote: "However, there is a way to ask these questions that avoids the inherent problems with shopping recommendations. For example, let’s say you wanted to buy a point-and-shoot camera that takes good low light photos. Here’s one way to ask:
Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera? A:Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.". That is a bit ridiculous. This best point-and-shoot camera recommendation is becoming as obsolete as a question about shopping recommendations.

Comment: @sebastien.b: You didn't read the whole page. You are quoting the *bad* example, which is obviously a bit ridiculous.